# Object has no attribute

Tags: python, multithreading

Please Help on my code with threads.  it goes like

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread): # Create a class representing a thread of control
        def __init__(self,target):
            print 'thread created'
            self.target = target
            threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )
        def run (self):
            print 'running thread '
            while True:
                self.target()
     # Define class to allow thread to be stopped over time
        def __init__ (self, target):
            super(MyThread, self).__init__()
            self._stop = threading.Event()
            print "thread stopped"
        def stop (self):
            self._stop.set()
        def stopped (self):
            return self._stop.isSet()
```

However when i run it, it complains that the line self.target () : 'MyThread' object has no attribute 'target'

how do i get around this?

Answer (score 4):

You have two **init** functions defined. The second definition (which doesn't define target) overrides the first.

Answer (score 0):

Uhm... you are overriding your own **init** method, and the override doesn't assign the self.target variable.